# Embed showcmd in airline

Tags: plugin-airline

How to embed first part of the command (operator pending mode) in airline? For example, I'd like to have separate section on the right side to show me this partial command.

If I set this simply with `:set showcmd`, it's displayed under airline status bar. Is it possible to have it displayed in the special section of the status bar, instead of beneath it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of `:set showcmd`, there's no way to programmatically access the currently typed command, so there's no chance to have airline (or any other plugin) display it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm just wondering if it's really impossible, considering airline displays for example mode (`:set showmode`), and even though I wasn't able to determine how exactly it sets `airline_current_mode` variable, it is still able to display correct mode, accessing it programmatically somehow.

Comment: You can get the current mode via the built-in `mode()` function; there's nothing similar for the typed command (yet).